# How would I add a section header sub-image based on path in Drupal?

Tags: 7, theming

A client has asked me to enter a graphic header (really a sub heading) on a site. This sub-heading graphic would fit nicely, side aligned into the `header` or `leader` region inside our subtheme based on Adaptive Theme.

I'm having a hard time figuring out *how* to best approach this.

**1. Do I use Context based on Path?** 
That is should I detect the path in Context and use one reaction to place an image into the `header` or `leader` region. I'm assuming I'd have to code about 12 HTML blocks. Though this doesn't exactly sit right with me.

**2. Use CSS logic**
Since I insert the first path level into the body class, should I add a div to the header region called `#sub-graphic` and use the following CSS logic:

```
body.sub-section-alpha #sub-graphic {background-image: url('image-alpha.jpg');}
body.sub-section-beta #sub-graphic {background-image: url('image-beta.jpg');}
```

**3. Other, better option**
Am I not seeing a simpler way.

Caveat: I'd prefer a non-php solution but I am comfortable inside theme functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution that Drupal provides.
You can create 2 blocks with images. Than set visability on different pages.
This is it.